# PHP - How do change the value of a string by + 1

Tags: php, character

Is there anyway in php I can ad 1 to the values of text?
Example:
a goes in the script
b comes out
Example:
Hello = Idmmp

Comment: I don't understand your question?

Comment: `$text = "text" . $var_from_script_b +1;` heck, I don't know. Show us come code; totally *unclear what you're asking*.

Comment: Do you mean you want the character value of each letter to add one to?

Comment: Your example seems incorrect, don't you mean `Ifmmf`?

Comment: I didn't understood your question. Can you explain in brief

Comment: He wants to change each letter in a string to the next alphabet letter.

Comment: He want to increase the "value" of the string by "1" for each letter. So "A" goes to "B", "C" goes to "D" whatsoever

Comment: I'm curious what happens if there's a Z in the string. What is expected?

Comment: We need to see a better example.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (didn't test it):

```
$var = "Hello";
$newString = array();  

for ($i = 0; $i<strlen($var); $i++)  {
    $newString[] = chr(ord($str[$i]) + 1); 
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php

Comment: As others have pointed out, you'll want to decide whether Z wraps around to A, or you'll get { when you hit Z.

Answer (score 1):

This code is more complicated but it makes shift in upper and lower cases separately and correctly makes shift for letter Z

```
function string_shift($string, $shift = 1) {
    // lowercase interval a-z 97-122
    // uppercase interval A-Z 65-90
    // interval length 26
    $len = strlen($string);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        $ord = ord($string[$i]);
        $is_lower = $ord >= 97 && $ord <= 122;
        $is_upper = $ord >= 65 && $ord <= 90; 
        if ($is_lower || $is_upper) {
            $left_shift = $is_lower ? 97 : 65; 
            $new_ord = $ord + $shift - $left_shift;
            $new_ord < 0 && $new_ord += 26; 
            $string[$i] = chr($new_ord % 26 + $left_shift);
        }   
    }   
    return $string;
}

//TEST
echo string_shift('abcABCzZ', 1); // bcdBCDaA
echo string_shift('abcABCzZ', -1); // zabZAByY
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
$my_string = "Hello";
$letters = str_split($my_string);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($letters); $i++) {
    $letters[$i]++;
}
$result = implode('', $letters);
```

You will probably also have to decide what to do with the letter `Z`.

Comment: You can't provide an empty delimiter to explode

Answer (score 0):

You should first split all the characters in the string and than use the `foreach` loop and than increment the character. Use the code Below

```
<?php
$string = "Hello";
$letters = str_split($string);
foreach($letters as $test)
{
 $test++;
 echo $test;
}
?>
```

You have to decide what do you want to do with the Alphabet Z because incrementing of `z` give `aa`. Hope this helps you